# Apache HTTP Server vs Oracle HTTP Server

Tags: oracle, apache, oracle11g

What is the difference between Apache HTTP Server and Oracle HTTP Server. What are the advantages/disadvantages of using Apache server , Oracle HTTP Server? Any insight into it is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 6):

It's helpful to know that Oracle HTTP Server (OHS) is the Apache HTTP Server (Apache). Specifically OHS is Apache 2.2.22 including critical bug fixes from higher Apache versions.  https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/webtier/HSADM/intro_ohs.htm#HSADM102
* This has been updated with OHS 12.2.1 now to Apache 2.4.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/webtier/administer-ohs/whats_new.htm#HSADM1277

OHS includes the WebLogic Server Proxy plugin (mod_wl_ohs) which brings frontend hosting to WebLogic application servers. OHS also includes configuration from the Fusion Middleware Control. Aside, this is of dubious value because you'll be editing the httpd.conf file through the advanced server configuration pages. An additional plus on the OHS side is all of the scripts and setup are generally in one place so there's less assembly of different bits such as with Apache. Finally, the control of OHS rests with the NodeManager daemon (usually) so that's one place to control WLS "Machines".

Bottom line OHS: OHS is a kinder-gentler way to be introduced to a slightly older version of Apache if you don't know Apache *well*. WLS plugins are included and if you're a WebLogic admin the Oracle docs are better. OHS is licensed by Oracle so it's not necessarily free, certainly not for support.

So to Apache's advantages. Since the mod_wl_ohs plugin can be downloaded separately, it can also be incorporated in an Apache installation. The configuration of the plugin is as involved as "normal" Apache httpd.conf edits, which is to say above-average complexity for those who have never worked with Apache HTTP Server. The server is also controlled from either init.d or systemd directly, as opposed to being controlled by nodemanager (which in turn is controlled by init.d/systemd).

Bottom line Apache: If you're a sysadmin who has already invested a lot in Apache, adding the WLS proxy plugin is pretty straight forward and you've gained everything OHS has to offer. But you'll have to kit it together yourself if you're a WLS administrator. Apache is licensed under the Apache 2.0, which is sort of a way of saying it's "free".

Answer (score 0):

I will kindly direct you [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e10144/intro_ohs.htm#HSADM462).

Its also important to note that if you maintain a valid support contract with Oracle and you user their HTTP server they will support that tier as well. So its another way you can lump as many products as you can into a support contract.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your insight. The features that are mentioned for OHS are also exist for Apache HTTP Server. Right? So apart from oracle's support what are the advantages of using OHS? Is there any performance/scalability advantages with OHS?Thanks!

Comment: I think your biggest advantages are going integration related. If you run SSO or other Oracle products you will find that OHS integrates _easier_ than apache/nginx.